# Tablediff.exe utility to compare Sybase and Sql server database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis, sybase

I am trying to use the tablediff.exe utility to compare and update a sybase and sql server 2008R2 table.

I wrote this statement:

```
exec master..xp_cmdshell '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\COM\tablediff.exe" -sourceserver HANU-302\newty -sourcedatabase SSISDBSource -sourcetable company -destinationserver SQL2008R2\HANU-302 -destinationdatabase SSISDBDest -destinationtable customer -f C:\Temp\Diff'
```

I am not sure as to what the sourceserver(the sybase database) name should be.

[image]

my sybase server is HANU-302 with port no 5000, the database name is newty and the table name is company.

I get the error as 'Unable to connect to Source HANU-302\newty.'

Comment: I'm not aware that you can use Tablediff against Sybase? Is there some documentation that indicates you can do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware that you can use Tablediff against Sybase? Is there some documentation that indicates you can do this?

In fact based on the parameters you give to TableDiff, it can only connect to a SQL Server. It's a SQL Server tool built by Microsoft so I don't think you can expect any different!

Comment: hmm..thanks, it seems like so. May be ill use some lookup to solve the issue of comparing the two tables.